# Dynamically Disable a jboss webservice

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws

I have a large project which deploys multiple web services. I would like to have different configurations under which certain web services are disabled at run-time. I've tried using the jboss-webservices deployment descriptor but the functionality seems very limited. Is there any efficient way to dynamically disable web-services at run-time?

Comment: Do you use a loadbalancer in front of your webservices? If yes, how are the possibilities to enable or disable there?

Comment: I do not use a loadbalancer. Ideally, I would like a way to dynamically disable certain port components directly within jboss-webservices.xml.